# Why do I see :" import of dart:mirrors is not supported in the current Dart runtime"

Tags: flutter

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Windows in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1
[ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(89)] Dart Error: error: import of dart:mirrors is not supported in the current Dart runtime
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_isolate.cc(144)] Could not prepare isolate.
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/runtime_controller.cc(417)] Could not create root isolate.
[ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(606)] Could not launch engine with configuration.
```

When I run the program, I see such errors...

Comment: A lot people task about this related to 'json_serializable' package. I disable all in my project still same thing happen.